# Decoding endian(?) data from a sensor

Tags: elixir, uart, nerves-project

I am not sure I even understand what is going on here with this data, but I am trying to replicate functionality like [here](https://community.openhab.org/t/air-quality-sensor-pms5003/8949/7), [here](https://github.com/jbanaszczyk/pms5003/blob/master/src/pms.h) or [here](https://github.com/fu-hsi/PMS/blob/master/src/PMS.cpp) to decode the data I am receiving over UART from my Plantower PMS5003 sensor (see [datasheet](https://github.com/avaldebe/AQmon/blob/master/Documents/PMS5003_LOGOELE.pdf)) sensor in Elixir.

It's delimited by `0x42` and `0x4d` and starts like this:

```
iex(mygadget@nerves.local)4> {:ok, data} = Circuits.UART.read(pid, 60000)
{:ok,
 <<66, 77, 0, 28, 0, 23, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 22, 0, 31, 0, 32, 17, 124, 4, 211, 0,
   171, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 151, 0, 4, 5, 66, 77, 0, 28, 0, 23, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0,
   22, 0, 31, 0, 32, ...>>}
```

I then base16 encode it:

```
iex(mygadget@nerves.local)5> Base.encode16(data)
"424D001C0017002000200016001F0020117C04D300AB00080000000097000405424D001C0017002000200016001F0020117C04D300AB00080000000097000405424D001C0017001F001F0016001E001F115804BE0098000800
000000970003B5424D001C0018002000200016001F002011BB04D8009F0008000000009700043E424D001C0016001F001F0015001E001F11DC04C3009300080000000097000437424D001C0017001E001E0015001D001E11E20
4C300850008000000009700042C424D001C0016001E001E0015001D001E117304B70087000600000000970003B0424D001C0016001D001D0015001D001D111F049B007B00060000000097000331424D001C0017001E001E0016
001E001E10F5048D007D00060000000097000400424D001C0017001E001E0016001E001E10FB0496008B0004000000009700041B424D001C0016001E001E0015001E001E10B304810089000400000000970003BA424D001C001
5001C001C0014001C001C104A045E008000020000000097000319424D001C0016001C001
```

And split by `424D`

```
decoded |> String.split("424D")
["", "001C0017002000200016001F0020117C04D300AB00080000000097000405",
 "001C0017002000200016001F0020117C04D300AB00080000000097000405",
 "001C0017001F001F0016001E001F115804BE0098000800000000970003B5",
 "001C0018002000200016001F002011BB04D8009F0008000000009700043E",
```

Then break it into chunks of 2

```
iex(mygadget@nerves.local)10> "001C0017002000200016001F0020117C04D300AB00080000000097000405" |> String.codepoints |> Enum.chunk(2) |> Enum.map(&Enum.join/1)
["00", "1C", "00", "17", "00", "20", "00", "20", "00", "16", "00", "1F", "00",
 "20", "11", "7C", "04", "D3", "00", "AB", "00", "08", "00", "00", "00", "00",
 "97", "00", "04", "05"]
```

I am fairly at a loss as to where to go from here. I found [this discussion about how to do it in Java](https://community.openhab.org/t/air-quality-sensor-pms5003/8949/7) but I don't really understand what is going on there with the framebuffers.

Any insight appreciated

EDIT: tags

Comment: Not sure where you want to go. Usually, you need to parse every frame received to extract your sensor measurement. Do you have the name and the documentation of your sensor somewhere ? it will tell you how to parse that.

Comment: You sure you want a C++ language tag on this? It may be the cause of some of the "Dude! WTF?!?" close votes.

Comment: Addressed these both - my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, erlang/elixir are great languages for deconstructing raw packets in binary format--which is what `Circuits.UART.read()` returns.  You deconstruct a binary, `<<...>>`, with [binary pattern matching](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1), and your datasheet contains the spec for the pattern you will use.  There's no need for base16 encoding, splitting at `424D`, nor breaking into chunks of 2:

```
defmodule My do

  def match(<<     
                66, 77, 
                _fr_len::big-integer-size(16),
                data1::big-integer-size(16),
                data2::big-integer-size(16),
                data3::big-integer-size(16),
                data4::big-integer-size(16),
                data5::big-integer-size(16),
                data6::big-integer-size(16),
                data7::big-integer-size(16),
                data8::big-integer-size(16),
                data9::big-integer-size(16),
                data10::big-integer-size(16),
                data11::big-integer-size(16),
                data12::big-integer-size(16),
                _reserved::big-integer-size(16),
                _check_code::big-integer-size(16),
                rest::binary
           >>) do

    IO.puts "pm 1.0 cf: #{data1} ug/m^3"
    IO.puts "pm 2.5 atmospheric: #{data5} ug/m^3"
    match(rest)
  end

  def match(partial_frame) do
    IO.puts "partial_frame:"
    IO.inspect partial_frame 
  end

  def go() do
    match(<<66, 77, 0, 28, 0, 23, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 22, 0, 31, 0, 32,  
           17, 124, 4, 211, 0, 171, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 151, 0, 4, 5,  
           66, 77, 0, 28, 0, 23, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 22, 0, 31, 0, 32>>)

    :ok
  end


end
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> My.go
pm 1.0 cf: 23 ug/m^3
pm 2.5 atmospheric: 31 ug/m^3
partial_frame:
<<66, 77, 0, 28, 0, 23, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 22, 0, 31, 0, 32>>
:ok
```

You could write `0x42, 0x4D` inside the pattern to exactly match the datasheet spec, however I think it's clearer to use the decimal equivalents, `66, 77`, because elixir doesn't output hex codes when outputting a binary, rather elixir outputs decimals--as can be seen in your `data` (Or, sometimes elixir outputs a double quoted string for a binary, which is really confusing and stupid.)  With `66, 77` in the pattern, you can easily look at the data and see where it matches.

Note that the last segment `rest::binary` is like writing `.*` in a regex.

Before trusting any of the data assigned to the variables, you should probably check that the frame length is 28 and verify the check code.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out what the check code represents.  I get `1029` for the check code.

==========

Can you post an example of what you expect the data to look like?

A hex string like `"1C"` is equivalent to decimal `28`.  You can get all the decimal equivalents like this:

```
data = [ "00", "1C", "00", "17", "00", "20", "00", "20", "00", "16", "00",   
        "1F", "00", "20", "11", "7C", "04", "D3", "00", "AB", "00", "08",  
        "00", "00", "00", "00", "97", "00", "04", "05"]

for str <- data do
  Integer.parse(str, 16)
end
|> IO.inspect
|> Enum.map(fn {a, _} -> a end)
```

[Integer.parse()](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Integer.html#parse/2) returns a tuple, where the first element is an integer and the second element is the "the remainder of the string", i.e. anything that couldn't be interpreted as an integer.

Output:

```
[
  {0, ""},
  {28, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {23, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {32, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {32, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {22, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {31, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {32, ""},
  {17, ""},
  {124, ""},
  {4, ""},
  {211, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {171, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {8, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {151, ""},
  {0, ""},
  {4, ""},
  {5, ""}
]
[0, 28, 0, 23, 0, 32, 0, 32, 0, 22, 0, 31, 0, 32, 17, 124,  
 4, 211, 0, 171, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 151, 0, 4, 5]
```

Is that what your data is supposed to look like?

It looks to me like the java code:

```
...forEach[b | bts.append(Integer.toHexString(b)]
```

does some bit twiddling with the [java's bitwise OR operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html): `|`, which makes no sense to me in that code snippet.  But, in elixir you would do that with [Bitwise.bor(a, b)](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Bitwise.html#bor/2). I really think that java code should look like this:

```
...forEach(b -> bts.append(Integer.toHexString(b))
```

In other words, forEach() takes a lambda as an argument.  Heck, that has me so curious, I'm going to ask the guy what that means.

Edit:

Alright, the guy responded to me, and that isn't Java--it is the syntax for a lambda though--in some DSL language.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. This might be interesting? https://github.com/avaldebe/AQmon/blob/master/Documents/PMS5003_LOGOELE.pdf

Comment: @Zen, See my new answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for taking the time to give me such a detailed and thoughtful answer. I haven't ever had to work with packets like this before and this made everything make a lot of sense. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Zen,  You're welcome! Was the data you posted accurate?  I'm curious why the check code for the first packet was `1029`. If I'm reading the datasheet correctly, I think the check code should always be `30`, which is the whole 32 byte packet/frame minus the 2 bytes for the check code.  To make sure the data isn't corrupt, you should probably do something like: `if fr_len == 28 and check_code == 30 do ...#read the data else #get next packet, i.e. match(rest)`

Comment: @Zen, Oh yeah, here is an [overview](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1) of the various designations you can use for each segment of a binary pattern.  There are a lot of defaults, which can make writing each segment shorter, but I find it's easier to specify everything.

Comment: thanks for that info as well. I'm implementing a library for this sensor now and that is really helpful.